# Go binary file is not running on linux EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a binary file that I've built via `go build` and I'm trying to run it on an Amazon Linux EC2 machine. But I'm getting this error:

`./main: ./main: cannot execute binary file.`

I tried the EC2 Ubuntu, Amazon Linux, but nothing seem to work. Can someone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That error usually appears when you compile the source code on a different CPU architecture than the machine you are running the binary on. Ensure the two machines are aligned as far as the architectures are concerned.

If you are experienced with [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), you could also use that to run your go binary from within a container. Then all you would have to do is install the docker client on your server and run the container on it.

Comment: Hello, Lawrence. Firstly, thanks for your answer.
I am building this binary via GitHub Actions using ubuntu-latest and storing as an Artifact, then using it. Do you think that could be causing the problem?

Comment: Do you know which architecture it is on? I'm looking for something like arm64, aarch64, x86, etc

Comment: It runs on "x86_64".

Comment: @GabrielBelloni ok and what is the architecture of the machine you are running on?

Comment: It is a x86_64 also - EC2 Amazon Linux 2023 AMI.

Comment: @GabrielBelloni So Ubuntu and AL2023 run on different linux families. I'm curious if you ran the build on a Red Hat based linux image (like CentOS for example) if it would work that way. Could you give it a try?

Comment: Lawrence, that still didn't work. What I'm doing is building the binary directly in the EC2 machine, that solved my problem for now. Is there something that you believe I can still try?